# How to change caller id during call in twilio

Tags: twilio

I have 2 phone numbers registered as caller ids in my twilio account.
Is is possible to change the caller id during call. Lets say i am using Phone 1 as a caller id but during call if user presses 1 he will be connected to other user. But Before connecting to other user i want that Phone 2 works as caller id.
Is it possible? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Based on your description of the workflow, I believe this is possible.

I assume you are using <Gather> to listen for Caller1 to indicate he wants to be connected to another call.  If thats the case, in the URL thats requested once Caller1 had pressed one, you're going to return some TwiML that includes the  <Dial> verb to tell Twilio to dial Caller2 and bridge them with Caller1.  The <Dial> verb has a callerID attribute that you can set to one of your verified caller ID's, and that is what will be shown to Caller2 when Twilio rings them.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dial-attributes

Hope that helps.